# как сохранять баланс в кликере js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, веб-программирование

Вопрос в том чтобы сохранить баланс после кликов пользователя. чтобы при обновлении сайта у него был этот баланс,только начинаю изучать веб,решил сделать простенький кликер . что может понадобиться ? помогите пожалуйста. вот код кликера
:

```css
  #wr {
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  width: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#wr input {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #c00;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
}

#plus {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d00;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#minus {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d00;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="vkui">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./clicker.css">

  <title>QB Coin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  </script>

  <div id="wr">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="count" value="0$" /><span id="plus">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var wrp = document.getElementById('wr');
    var countInput = document.getElementById('count');
    var plus = document.getElementById('plus');
    var units = countInput.value.replace(/\d/g, '');
    plus.onclick = function() {
      countInput.value = parseInt(countInput.value) + 1 + units;
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 варианта. Сохранять результат в куки ([`cookies`](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)), либо использовать [`localStorage`](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage) для той же цели. LocalStorage может хранить больше данных.

Comment: localStorage если я не запутался сохраняет данные только текущего пользователя? и его баланс должен  будет виден всем

Comment: localStorage хранит данные локально на компьютере пользователя. Они не будут доступны кому-либо ещё, кроме этого пользователя.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Trojan, для того, чтобы результат бы виден всем - нужен сервак. Точнее, БД, к которой можно будет обращаться извне. Если будете сами у себя на ПК настраивать, то это надо подключить, развернуть правильно, настроить переадресацию портов и купить белый ip. Если покупать хостинг, то надо платить деньги, но сразу будет хостинг, на котором можно будет разместить кликер.

Comment: @DaniilKedrov, забыли упомянуть, что `cookie` тоже доступны только пользователю. Для вывода информации для всех нужна БД)

Comment: Чтобы баланс был виден всем, нужно внешнее хранилище, самый простой вариант = хостинг. Далее начнутся нюансы - допустим,идентифицируем пользователя по сохраненным кукам,это не будет работать при смене устройства. Уже нужна авторизация.. И т.д.